# Google Cloud Functions Promises execution and return

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I have a Google Cloud maintenance function I wish to run to update a Firebase Real-time Database.
The code is pretty straight forward, but for some reason the execution finishes before all code is run. 
I suspect that my await call is not handled as expected because I am miss-using .once()?

```
exports.setUserLimits = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('/NO-TRIGGER')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  let myPromises = []
  const userNodeSnap = await database.ref('users').once('value')
  console.log('numChildren', userNodeSnap.numChildren())
  userNodeSnap.forEach(async (userSnap) => {
    console.log('Process user', userSnap.key)
    const userData = userSnap.val()
    //Set user limits
    const limits = {items:10, logins:1}
    console.log('New limits', limits)
    myPromises.push(userSnap.ref.update({limits}))
  })

  // Execute all promises
  console.log('myPromises lenght', myPromises.length)
  return Promise.all(myPromises)
  .then(()=>{
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.error('Could not execute all promises', err)
    // Show must go on!
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
})
```

Logout from Google Cloud Functions

```
setUserLimits Function execution started
numChildren 4
Process user 1234567890
myPromises lenght 0
Function execution took 416 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
New limits {items:10, logins:1}
```

The execution finishes prematurely resulting in only one record being updated.

Replacing the last lines to below generates the same result

```
await Promise.all(myPromises)
```

/K

Comment: Have you tried "await"ing your Promise.all()? The function doesn't have to return anything, just wrap that "await Promise.all()" with a try-catch block to catch any errors.

Comment: Hi Scarysize! Sorry, same result. /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at this block of code:

```
  userNodeSnap.forEach(async (userSnap) => {
    console.log('Process user', userSnap.key)
    const userData = userSnap.val()
    //Set user limits
    const limits = {items:10, logins:1}
    console.log('New limits', limits)
    myPromises.push(userSnap.ref.update({limits}))
  })
```

we see that it has the logical form:

```
someArray.forEach(async function(element) {
  // do something
});
```

Basically, code after the `forEach` function call can execute before the completion of processing of each element of the aray.

Comment: Hi Kolban! That actually makes sense and explains the logging result. :) Then the question is: How do I make the code wait for the forEach() to finish before proceeding?  :D /K

Comment: I suspect this article can hold the answer https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/

Comment: In your logic, you seem to be doing "something" for each element in the array.  You have asked to do this "something" asynchronously by tagging the forEach callback as "async".  If you remove the "async" tag from your forEach callback then the callback will process each element in the array synchrnously and the whole forEach will not conclude until each element has been addressed.  My "gut" is saying "simply remove the async modifier from the forEach callback".

Comment: Yes! Removing the "async" worked! Many thanks \(^__^)/  /K